# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" with gcc in Terminal

Tags: macos, gcc

So I'm trying to compile a C code but I keep getting this error. After reading a lot of older posts with this issue I'm not really understanding the jargon so the solutions are going over my head. The command I use is `/usr/local/bin/gcc-9 -I/usr/local/include/ ARES_v2.c`

The error I get is pretty long

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ffclos", referenced from:
      _read_fits_file in ccKuUiJh.o
  "_ffgipr", referenced from:
      _read_fits_file in ccKuUiJh.o
  "_ffgky", referenced from:
      _read_fits_file in ccKuUiJh.o
  "_ffgpxv", referenced from:
      _read_fits_file in ccKuUiJh.o
  "_ffopentest", referenced from:
      _read_fits_file in ccKuUiJh.o
  "_ffrprt", referenced from:
      _read_fits_file in ccKuUiJh.o
  "_gsl_blas_dnrm2", referenced from:
      _fitngauss in ccKuUiJh.o

And it keeps going from there. I can attach the code I'm trying to compile but it's pretty long so hopefully the error itself can shed some light. If anything else needs added I certainly can add it.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/gcc-9 -I/usr/local/include/ ARES_v2.c -lcfitsio -lm -lnsl -lsocket`?

Comment: "library not found for -lcfitsio"

Comment: Have you downloaded fitsio manually somehow? I'm guessing the code includes fitsio.h, where is that located? You may need to point out the location of the library with `-L<directory where the library is located>`

Comment: So I have over a dozen fitsio.h files scattered throughout my computer (probably due to downloading a bunch of other programs that included the code), but after choosing one to go with and using the -L option in conjunction with the above, I always get "gcc-9: error: ARES_v2.c: No such file or directory" no matter which .h file I point to.

Comment: So I was able to get rid of that error, but now I'm getting "library not found for -lnsl". Do I need to use the -L option and point to where each of these libraries should be?

Comment: Try removing the -lnsl part, not sure whether it’s required for macos

Comment: That got rid of that error but it also can't find socket, which when I get rid of -lsocket returns the initial architecture x86_64 error.

Comment: This code was made mainly for Unix/Linux quite awhile ago so I'm starting to think it can't compile with the Mac OS X without serious revisions of which I'm not qualified to do